# parent id hierarchy identification MS SqlServer2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this code

```
            create table #temp
        (
            order_id int not null identity(1,1) primary key
            ,sid int
            ,created_date date
            ,parent_order_id int
        )

        insert into #temp
        (
             sid
            ,created_date

        )values(1,'2017-01-01') 

        insert into #temp
        (
             sid
            ,created_date
            ,parent_order_id

        )values(1,'2017-02-01',1),(1,'2017-03-01',2),(1,'2017-04-01',3)



        insert into #temp
        (
             sid
            ,created_date

        )values(1,'2017-06-01')

        insert into #temp
        (
             sid
            ,created_date
            ,parent_order_id

        )values(1,'2017-07-01',5),(1,'2017-08-01',6) 

        select * from #temp
```

Whenever parent_order_id is null which indicates it is a new order. After that customer can add items associated to that order. so we have parent_order_id filled for these associations. But I want to know what is the first order_id for each association child order.I am looking for an output like below.

```
    `order_id   sid     created_date    parent_order_id   original_order_id
        1           1           2017-01-01      NULL                1
        2           1           2017-02-01      1                   1
        3           1           2017-03-01      2                   1
        4           1           2017-04-01      3                   1
        5           1           2017-06-01      NULL                4
        6           1           2017-07-01      5                   4
        7           1           2017-08-01      6                   4
```

`
any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into using a recursive CTE. But also something seems off in your db design if you have to use the ordinal position of data to determine hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

With the following piece of code you can get results you are expecting.

```
;WITH cte (order_id, original_order_id)
AS
(
    SELECT order_id, order_id AS original_order_id 
    FROM #temp WHERE parent_order_id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT o.order_id AS order_id, cte.original_order_id AS original_order_id 
    FROM #temp AS o
    JOIN cte
      ON o.parent_order_id = cte.order_id 
)

SELECT #temp.order_id, #temp.sid, #temp.created_date, #temp.parent_order_id, cte.original_order_id 
FROM #temp
JOIN cte ON cte.order_id=#temp.order_id
ORDER BY cte.order_id
```

Please be aware, that there are certain limits on recursion as this for CTE. Currently it is 100 which can be pushed up to 32767.